# How to use dynamic alerts for login form?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I am new at Oracle development using oracle 10g Forms.

I am trying to write this code for login purpose. When user enters wrong password, it gives alert in popup window. Also, when user enters wrong username, it raise an alert.

I wrote this code but I am unable to correct it.

```
DECLARE
    un    VARCHAR (15);
    pwd   VARCHAR (15);
BEGIN
    --- Dynamic altert properties code start--
    SET_ALERT_PROPERTY ('LOGIN_ALERTS', TITLE, 'Security Altert');
    SET_ALERT_PROPERTY ('LOGIN_ALERTS',
                        ALERT_MESSAGE_TEXT,
                        'Wrong Username?');
    SET_ALERT_PROPERTY ('LOGIN_ALERTS',
                        ALERT_MESSAGE_TEXT,
                        'Wrong Password?');

    SELECT username, users_password
      INTO un, pwd
      FROM MENU_USERS
     WHERE username = :TXT_USERNAME;
        IF un = :TXT_USERNAME
        THEN
            IF pwd = :TXT_PWD
            THEN
                CALL_FORM ('F:\ISMS\INV\inv_stock.fmx');
            ELSE
                SHOW_ALERT ('LOGIN_ALERTS');
            END IF;
        ELSE
            SHOW_ALERT ('LOGIN_ALERTS');
        END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alerts are OK, but - consecutive `message` calls will do as well. This example shows how to use that approach.

Code you wrote is kind of "wrong" as it doesn't handle "wrong username" situation. When that happens, `select` won't return anything and will raise the `no_data_found` exception which should be handled.

Here you go:

```
declare
  pwd varchar2(15);
begin
  select users_password
    into pwd
    from menu_users
    where username = :txt_username;

  -- if TXT_USERNAME value exists, SELECT will return its password
  if pwd = :txt_pwd then
     call_form('whichever form you want');
  else
     message('Wrong password');
     message('Wrong password');
     raise form_trigger_failure;
  end if;

exception
  when no_data_found then
    -- SELECT didn't return anything, but raised an exception
    message('Wrong username');
    message('Wrong username');
end;
```